# Question on Statistics/Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Jill has two admirers: Bob and Dave. Each night, with probability 1/3 she dreams of Bob, with probability 1/3 she dreams of Dave, and otherwise she dreams
of Bruce. Assume that all dreams are mutually independent.

Estimate the probability that during one year she will dream of Bruce more nights than of both of her admirers all together.

I originally though to model this with a Poisson distribution since they are independant, but I couldn't seem to get it to work. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a binomial distribution problem. If the probability of success is 1/3 in each trial, what is the probability of 122 or more successes in 365 trials.

Comment: Why 122, surely it could be any number since there is no set amount for the other two people?

Comment: Based on the word "otherwise" in the problem, I assumed that on any given night Jill dreams of exactly one person, Bob, Dave, or Bruce but dreams are independent across nights. If she can independently dream Bob, Dave, and Bruce in a night, then the event "she will dream of Bruce more nights than of both of her admirers all together" should clarify whether the nights when she dreams of both her admirers counts as 1 or 2 a night on which she dreams both of Bob and Dave.

Comment: So I would do X ~ B(365, 1/3). And find P(X>=122)?

Comment: Yes, that is my interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Let the r.v. $X_1$ be the number of times in one year that she dreams of Bruce. This random variable is binomially distributed with $n=365, p=\frac{1}{3}$. You simply want to calculate the probability: $$P(X_1\ge365/2)=P(X_1\ge182.5)=P(X_1\ge183).$$
(That is because, the only possibility to dream more times about Bruce than about the other two, is to dream about him more than half of the days! Think about it).

Now since: $n\cdot p=365\cdot\frac{1}{3}=121.67>5$ and $n\cdot q=365\cdot\frac{2}{3}=243.3>5$ and $n>30$ you can use the normal approximation instead of the Poisson approximation of the binomial distribution. That is, according to the Central Limit Theorem, the r.v. $X_1$ has approximately the distribution $$X_1 \sim N(\mu=n\cdot p,\,\sigma^2=n\cdot p\cdot q)$$
or equivalently $$X_1 \sim N(\mu=121.67,\,\sigma^2=81.11)$$
So, the desired probability is equal to $$P(X_1\ge183)=P(Z\ge\frac{183-121.67}{\sqrt{81.11}})=P(Z\ge6.81)=1-\Phi(6.81)=1-1=0.$$
If you use Excel 2010 instead you can use the expression $$=1-BINOM.DIST(182;365;1/3;TRUE)$$ which is again equal to zero. This is the exact probability.